# How to access the elements of global 2d arrays in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, global-variables

I am new to C. I declared a 2D global array:

```
int allhospitalsdata[4][3] = {{1,100,0},{2,200,0},{3,300,0},{4,400,0}};
```

Then I try to access the value at some index like that:

```
if (allhospitalsdata[hospitalid][3]<allhospitalsdata[hospitalid][2])
  {
      //do something
  }
  else
  {
      //do another thing
  }
```

When testing the condition, it always goes to the `else` block. Why?

Comment: An array with 3 elements has index 0, 1 and 2. However, 3 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're accessing the 4th element of `allhospitalsdata[hospitalid]`, which only contains three elements. In fact, C doesn't prevent you from accessing an array at an invalid index. You have to take care of that yourself. What happens is that in `allhospitalsdata[hospitalid][3]` (which isn't part of your array!) there is stored something undefined, which, by observing the `if` condition, is probably greater than or equal to zero. That's why it goes into the `else` block.

Please note that arrays in C are always zero-indexed, thus `allhospitalsdata[0]` refers to the data of the *first* hospital.

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but imagine the 2D array as a table with rows and columns. For `a[x][y]`, `x` is used to access a row while `y` is used to access a column *in that row*.

If something else has been your question, then please clarify.